# SQL Server : duplicate counts

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct-values

I have the following.  But in the final result some of the employee ID's are counted twice. My goal is to only count distinct `employeeID` for the `[UniqueEmployees]` column... Can someone please help me?

This is the code here:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#GG') IS NOT NULL
      DROP TABLE #GG

SELECT DISTINCT 
    [month], vv.Hiremonth,
    LoanNumber, vv.EmployeeId,
    agentname, 
    vv.YearsOfService, vv.MonthsofService,
    vv.TenureGrouping, vv.TenureMonthGrouping,
    manager,
    SUM([Call Counts]) as Calls,
    SUM(opportunities) as Opportunities,
    SUM([Discussed w/Customer]) as [Discussed w/Customer],
    SUM(DidNotDiscuss) as [DidNotDiscuss],
    SUM(CustomerInterested) as CustomerInterested,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT MGR.EmployeeId)
     FROM #MANAGERS MGR
     WHERE --EmployeeId = EmployeeId    
           --and 
           CAST(CONVERT(datetime, RIGHT(MGR.HireMonth, 4) + LEFT(MGR.HireMonth, 2) + '01') as DATE) <= CAST(CONVERT(datetime, right([Month], 4) + left([Month], 2) + '01') as DATE)
          --and MonthsOfService = MonthsOfService
          --and YearsOfService = YearsOfService
    ) as UniqueEmployees
INTO
    #GG
FROM
    #FINALtemp2b VV
--left join 
    --(select distinct Employeeid
     --from #FINALtemp2b) CC
     --on CC.EmployeeId = VV.EmployeeId
GROUP BY 
    [month], vv.Hiremonth, LoanNumber, vv.EmployeeId,
    agentname, vv.YearsOfService, vv.MonthsofService,
    vv.TenureGrouping, vv.TenureMonthGrouping, manager
ORDER BY
    [month]
```

Comment: Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `count(distinct ...)` is correct. That said, you are using too many temporary tables we don't know about. Can you reduce your query to a minimal example, including an input to show it does not work?

Comment: can you add the employee_id in the select and group by it, then it will show which ones are counted twice and it may give you some insights about why they are counted twice.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the first 'distinct' and the excess 'select'.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#GG') is not null Drop Table #GG
select *
into  #GG
from (
    select 
        [month],
        vv.Hiremonth,
        LoanNumber,
        vv.EmployeeId,
        agentname, 
        vv.YearsOfService,
        vv.MonthsofService,
        vv.TenureGrouping,
        vv.TenureMonthGrouping,
        manager,
        SUM([Call Counts]) as Calls,
        sum(opportunities) as Opportunities,
        sum([Discussed w/Customer]) as [Discussed w/Customer],
        sum(DidNotDiscuss) as [DidNotDiscuss],
        sum(CustomerInterested) as CustomerInterested,
        count(distinct (MGR.EmployeeId))
    from #MANAGERS MGR
    where cast(convert(datetime,right(MGR.HireMonth,4) + left(MGR.HireMonth,2) + '01') as DATE) <= cast(convert(datetime,right([Month],4) + left([Month],2) + '01') as DATE)
    group by
        [month],
        vv.Hiremonth,
        LoanNumber,
        vv.EmployeeId,
        agentname, 
        vv.YearsOfService,
        vv.MonthsofService,
        vv.TenureGrouping,
        vv.TenureMonthGrouping,
        manager

) as UniqueEmployees
```

Comment: hi.  I would prefer to keep the VV aliased table in the picture.